# Angular 2 - Drag & Drop call back functions

Tags: angular, callback, drag-and-drop

**Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/uZ8mvu6a1LXAsBBY3Shd?p=preview**

In the top part I has ‘widgets’ : ‘Text a’ and ‘Text b’ that you can drag and drop.

Below widgets you got two rows with widgets already inside.
I've a

- Block  containers

  - Block row ( the blue background)

    - Block column  (the pink background)

      - Block ( the red background)

basically like a Bootstrap grid.

1) When I drag the 'text a’ widget over the red block, the widget gets added but i don’t get the callback **‘onDragEnter’** function called. I get only in the console.log  **onDropSucces**s.

I would like to get a call back when I drag the widget over the container, row, column and block so that I could add logic.

I tried adding my functions, but doesn't work and can't figure out where the mistake is.

I hope some can help to figure this one.

```
  //Drag functions

        drop(item){
            alert('dropped')
            console.log('dropping event', item)
                var target = item.mouseEvent.target,
                  index;

                if(target.classList.contains('row')) {
                    index = target.getAttribute('data-index');
                }

                if(target.classList.contains('item') && target.parentNode.classList.contains('row')) {
                    index = target.parentNode.getAttribute('data-index');
                }

                if(index) {
                    console.log(this.containers);
                    console.log(this.containers[index]);
                    this.containers[index].widgets.push( item.dragData);
                } else {
                    this.containers.push([ item.dragData]);
                }
         }
         onDropSuccess(widget: any, event: any, objecType: string) {
            console.log('dropped on ', objecType)
            if( objecType == 'row'){
                console.log('dropped on', objecType)
            }
            else if(objecType == 'block'){
                console.log('dropped on ', objecType)
            }
            this.dragOperation = false;
            console.log('onDropSuccess x', widget, event);

            console.log('containers', this.containers)
         }

         onDragStart(widget: any, event: any) {
            console.log('onDragStart', widget, event);
         }

         onDragEnter(widget: any, event: any) {
            alert('entered ')
            console.log('onDragEnter', widget, event);
            console.log('drag enter containers', this.containers)
         }

           chicken(event) {
            console.log('onDragEnter chicken', event);

         }

         onDragSuccess(widget: any, event: any) {
            console.log('onDragSuccess', widget, event);
         }

         onDragOver(widget: any, event: any) {
            console.log('onDragOver', widget, event);
         }

         onDragEnd(widget: any, event: any) {
            console.log('onDragOver', widget, event);
         }
         onDragLeave(widget: any, event: any) {
            console.log('onDragLeave', widget, event);
         }

         onMouseDown(){
            this.dragOperation = true;
            console.log('mouse down');
         }

         onMouseUp(event: any){
            console.log(event);
            this.dragOperation = false;
         }
```

Comment: have you considered using the power of RxJS to do this?

Comment: pls explain more , what's your idea and how. As I am a newbie to this

Comment: this is quite a good example: https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-simple-drag-and-drop-with-observables

Comment: @Danimal, I started a bounty, as can't get my head around it ::(

Comment: I dont have much idea about this library but i would recommand using ng2-dragula. This library have good callback and events. https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is add two things to your items in your html.

The first is this

```
(dragover)="$event.preventDefault()"
```

What it will do is this makes it so that it allows you to drop into that item, which you are already handling elsewhere, but by doing it here this allows you to register for the next call back.

The next thing you need to add is this

```
(dragenter)="onDragEnter('',$event)"
```

This will actually call the onDragEnter function, and link the event to it. 
 You can of course change the parameters to match what you need.

As for the plunker, you can add these two to your plunker at line 38 and it works, this way you don't have to try to understand a new architecture.

NOTE: I recommend you don't use an alert in onDragEnter(like it currently has) as you will get spammed with them.

I would also recommend looking at https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp as it gives very easy to use explanation on how to use the event for drag and drop.

If you need more help I would be more than happy to help, just let me know where your confusion is.

Comment: I have done what you recommend. but don't understand why I get two alerts, on dragEnter is only once on the page, but I see that  that when I drag over it calls and than again . Here my plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/BeqfGyPQe4GKVatZNWYG?p=preview

Comment: It looks like it has to do with the adding of the element to the blue container, so you get on dragEnter on the red box that was there(the Lorem Ipsum one) and then it creates your new red box, and it sees an ondragenter on that box as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can just change Your event Name onDragEnter to dragEnter 
i just fork your example in new plunkr  [Plunkr link][1]

```
 [1]: https://plnkr.co/edit/88aBdI1WOeJ7MvEvnAKm?p=preview
```

Comment: I have tested your plunker and dragEnter does not work. If I drag the element over the pink color it does not run the onDragEnter function that calls Alert .

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are new to angular 2. I recommend using a standard library to do a drag and drop operation. 2 good options that I know of are [ng2-dragula](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula) and [ng2-dnd](https://github.com/akserg/ng2-dnd). I have found ng2-dnd to be much better and have shifted to it from ng-dragula in one of my projects.

Comment: Hi Prabhat, I am using ng2-dnd :)

Comment: No Prabhat, I trying to figure out the library, that what the question is about :)